# pip install does not work with python3 on windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch

I am getting acquainted with python development and it's been some time since I wrote python code. I am setting up my IDE (Pycharm) and Python3 binaries on Windows 10.

I want to start working with the pytorch library and I am used to before in python2 just typing pip install  and it works fine.

Now it seems pip is not installed by default and has been replaced by something called conda?

What's the best way to install the pytorch package from the command line?

here is a screenshot [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSDBD.jpg)

Comment: about your screenshot, of course you get and error, the commands I show you are to be executed in the console, not inside the python interpreter (that you can also open inside the console)

Comment: Not what you have asked for, but when using PyCharm, I would recommend installing packages from within PyCharm. PyCharm takes care of choosing the right Python interpreter (at least it shows you which one is currently selected). That avoids installing packages for another interpreter than the one you are using in PyCharm.

Answer (score 1):

[PyTorch Documentation](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/) does have a selector that will give you the commands for pip and conda.

However, Python3 should have pip installed, it may just be pip3 (that's what it was for me).

Answer (score 0):

if you have multiple version of python installed, you need to call the specific pip of that version to install for that version like

```
C:\Users\copperfield\Desktop>python -m pip install some_library
```

you can check the version by

```
C:\Users\copperfield\Desktop>python --version
```

but if you have multiples version you might need to append a number to it in order to differentiate between version so call it as `python3` or python3x or python3.x where x is the specific version so for example for python 3.10 that is `python310` or `python3.10`

---

Note, you can enter your python interpreter in your console by simply calling python (or python3 in your case), to get out of it simply call `exit()`

```
C:\Users\copperfield\Desktop>python
Python 3.10.4 (tags/v3.10.4:9d38120, Mar 23 2022, 23:13:41) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print("hello world")
hello world
>>> exit()

C:\Users\copperfield\Desktop>
```

the pip calls (as show previously) are to be executed in the console, not in the interpreter

Comment: I opened python3 from the command line (after having to configure windows to open the proper binary for python3) and I get the following error when I try to run the commands you suggested.

Thanks all for your replies and help. `code`>>> pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'pip' is not defined. Did you mean: 'zip'?
>>> pip install pytorch
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    pip install pytorch
        ^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax `code` [link](https://imgur.com/a/AdMiI1j)

Comment: @stackom100 that is because you entered your python interpreter, just exit from it and call `>python3 -m pip install pytorch` and that should do it